# Did I sin after trying to help a sick kitten but it died?

Tags: gods, belief, sin

I found a sick kitten by the road. I simply couldn't leave it. I brought it home and applied medicines on it. I fed it food and made it a warm place to sleep using cardboard boxes. The next day, its health improved and it was recovering well. But at night, it died suddenly. I gave it a burial funeral. I'm so sorry for the kitten but also I'm at mental unrest thinking if I've sinned as my actions, even though well-intentioned, could've led to its death. Also, it's Navratri. I feel like I've made Goddess Durga angry. All I wanted to do was to help it. Some bad things started happening to me after its death. I feel like gods and godesses, especially Goddess Durga, is angry with me. If I've sinned, how to ask for the forgiveness and wash away my sins ?

Comment: It is just like asking I took the life of five cockroaches and 3 mosquitoes and I'm afraid that the god is angry with it. Sin and Sinner, both are an illusion.